# search on 'open' dialog is out-of-date

Tags: nautilus, gui

If I have saved a file recently (or even on the last couple of days), it does not show up on searches on that "open dialog" some programs have

(The "open dialog of programs" is the following. It appears on libreoffice and on firefox)

[image]

I am wondering why this search is not up-to-date: what is the infrastructure behind this search ? Does it update some sort of index from time to time ? How could I configure it to do so more frequently ?

Comment: it would also be nice to know **how** you figured out what engine is behind that search

Comment: uhm... just a guess, but try to run `sudo updatedb` in a terminal, and then check the search again.

Answer (score 1):

The `Recently Used` list you referring to is stored as an xml file `~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel`. Following is an example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xbel version="1.0"
      xmlns:bookmark="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/desktop-bookmarks"
      xmlns:mime="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info"
>
  <bookmark href="file:///home/Usename/Firewall/fwbuilder.fwb" added="2012-11-07T04:33:55Z" modified="2012-12-20T05:31:26Z" visited="2012-11-07T04:33:55Z">
    <info>
      <metadata owner="http://freedesktop.org">
        <mime:mime-type type="application/octet-stream"/>
        <bookmark:applications>
          <bookmark:application name="fwbuilder" exec="&apos;fwbuilder %u&apos;" modified="2012-12-20T05:31:26Z" count="4"/>
        </bookmark:applications>
      </metadata>
    </info>
  </bookmark>
  <bookmark href="file:///home/Usename/Desktop/limit_test.py" added="2012-12-16T04:48:29Z" modified="2012-12-16T06:02:28Z" visited="2012-12-16T04:48:30Z">
    <info>
      <metadata owner="http://freedesktop.org">
        <mime:mime-type type="text/x-python"/>
        <bookmark:groups>
          <bookmark:group>gedit</bookmark:group>
        </bookmark:groups>
        <bookmark:applications>
          <bookmark:application name="gedit" exec="&apos;gedit %u&apos;" modified="2012-12-16T06:02:28Z" count="16"/>
        </bookmark:applications>
      </metadata>
    </info>
  </bookmark>
  <bookmark href="file:///home/Usename/Firewall/gateway.int.apple.com.fw" added="2012-12-20T05:32:03Z" modified="2012-12-20T05:35:25Z" visited="2012-12-20T05:32:03Z">
    <info>
      <metadata owner="http://freedesktop.org">
        <mime:mime-type type="application/x-shellscript"/>
        <bookmark:groups>
          <bookmark:group>gedit</bookmark:group>
        </bookmark:groups>
        <bookmark:applications>
          <bookmark:application name="gedit" exec="&apos;gedit %u&apos;" modified="2012-12-20T05:35:25Z" count="3"/>
        </bookmark:applications>
      </metadata>
    </info>
  </bookmark>
</xbel>
```

It is a facility/feature of the GTK+ library/framework.

The reason of inconsistency between software, including software using GTK+, is because author of individual package/software may choose to use or not use it. There is no law/rule to enforce that. Some author may choose to not provide a recent list in their software. Some may implement their own. Some may use it with filter for file type(file extension).

There is no right or wrong about this. This also happen to software running on other OS, not only Linux.

Comment: well, that is a step in the right direction: this dialog is from GTK

Comment: now ... My question reffered to the search dialog, not the recently used

Comment: Do you have multiple file system or network share? Are the inconsistency between file system / local / network ?